# Javascript Plotly for loop for Y axis returns NaN after a couple iterations

Tags: javascript, python, for-loop, plotly, nan

This has got to be the most bizarre error I've ever come across... here goes.

So I'm creating Javascript ports of MATLAB programs for a math professor at my university to use on her website. Because I don't feel like messing around with the University's IT department to allow me to run some kind of web server, I have decided to script it all on the front-end just using javascript with the Plotly.js framework.

The way the charts are set up is I use the scatterplot type with different "vectors", or just arrays, for the X and Y axis. The X axis is simply all integers from 0 to the "timeBox" value.

The issue presents itself when I try to populate the resulting Y axis arrays. The equations themselves are predator/prey relationships that my professor gave me. I thought the issue may lie in the equations, though a quick Python script dispelled this.

I have placed the array building code into functions so that they may be called by my updateGraph() function, which is called whenever any of my HTML GUI elements undergoes "change". Here is my HTML:

#### Predator and Prey Model

```
    <strong>Attributes:</strong><br>

    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <label>Prey: </label><input type="number" class = "input" id="preyBox" value="1.1" step="0.1" style="display:inline-block; width: 20%;"/>
    </div> <br>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <label>Predator: </label><input type="number" class = "input" id="predBox" value="0.4" step="0.1" style="display:inline-block; width: 20%;"/>
    </div> <br>

    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <label>Time: </label><input type="number" class = "input" id="timeBox" min = "0" value="10" style="display:inline-block; width: 20%;"/>
    </div> <br>

    <div style="display:inline-block">
    <label>r: 0</label><input type="range" class = "input" id="rRange" value = "1.3" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" style="width:20%"/><label>10</label>
    </div><br>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
    <label>u: 0</label><input type="range" class = "input" id="uRange" value = "0.7" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" style="width:20%"/><label>1</label>
    </div><br>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
    <label>K: 0</label><input type="range" class = "input" id="KRange" value = "1" min="0" max="100" style="width:20%"/><label>100</label>
    </div><br>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
    <label>s: 0</label><input type="range" class = "input" id="sRange" value = "0.5" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" style="width:20%"/><label>10</label>
    </div><br>
    <div style="display:inline-block">
    <label>v: 0</label><input type="range" class = "input" id="vRange" value = "1.6" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" style="width:20%"/><label>10</label>
    </div>
```

and the Javascript which returns correct values for my arrays then abruptly returns only NaN. I know it goes through the entire for loop because the length of the arrays are still the same as the length of my x vector, which is the timeBox value.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener("change", updateGraph);
}

var x = {'vector': new Array()}
var y = {
  'preyVector': new Array(),
  'predVector': new Array(),
}

function valueOf(element){
    return parseFloat(document.getElementById(element).value)
}
function adjustX(){
  x.vector = new Array()
    for(var i = 0; i < valueOf("timeBox"); i++){
        x.vector[i] = i
    }
}
function adjustYPrey(){
  y.preyVector = new Array()
    y.preyVector[0] = valueOf("preyBox")
    for(var i = 0; i < x.vector.length - 1; i++){
        //y.preyVector[i+1] = parseFloat(y.preyVector[i]) * (1+(valueOf("rRange")*(1-(parseFloat(y.preyVector[i])/valueOf("KRange"))))) - (valueOf("sRange") * parseFloat(y.preyVector[i]) * parseFloat(y.predVector[i]))
    y.preyVector[i+1] = y.preyVector[i] * (1+valueOf("rRange")*(1-y.preyVector[i]/valueOf("KRange"))) - valueOf("sRange")*y.preyVector[i]*y.predVector[i]
    console.log(y.preyVector[i+1])
    if(isNaN(y.preyVector[i+1])) {
      console.log("something fishy here")
    }
    }

}
function adjustYPred(){
  y.predVector = new Array()
    y.predVector[0] = valueOf("predBox");
    for(var i = 0; i < x.vector.length - 1; i++){
        y.predVector[i+1] = (1-valueOf("uRange"))*y.predVector[i] + valueOf("vRange")*y.predVector[i] * y.preyVector[i]

    }
}
```

I have basically tried everything. Below is my Python code which of course works perfectly fine. For each variable I simply entered the default values from the HTML. I can confirm this works based on the MATLAB implementation.

```
x = []
for i in range(10):
    x.append(i)
preyInitial = 1.1
predInitial = 0.4

prey = [None]*len(x)
pred = [None]*len(x)

r = 1.3
u = 0.7
K = 1
s = 0.5
v = 1.6

prey[0] = preyInitial
pred[0] = predInitial

def plot():
  for i in range(len(x)-1):
    prey[i + 1] = prey[i] * (1+r*(1-prey[i]/K)) - s*prey[i]*pred[i]
    pred[i + 1] = (1-u)*pred[i] + v*prey[i]*pred[i]

  print("Prey data:\n", prey[:])
  print("Predator data:\n", pred[:])

plot()
```

Thank you so much for your help, I am frankly dumbfounded and I am cementing an unnecessary hatred for Javascript that I don't want to have.

Comment: I would suspect a division of 0 by 0. I don't see how it can happen, but I would break down the calculations into small pieces and print out everything that happens.

Comment: Hmm, this was actually good advice as it prevented me from problems later down the road -my K value was the only denominator, and had a minimum value of 0- though this did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face.

It was unwise to split the adjust Y functions into two separate functions, since they both relied on one another to be completed simultaneously. I still don't know precisely why Javascript decided to stop after 3 iterations, but my guess is that one function "got ahead" of the other around that time and caused a discrepancy, so one function was multiplying a non-existent value, resulting in NaN.

Here is the updated code for anyone in the same boat as me:

```
function adjustY(){
  y.preyVector = new Array()
    y.preyVector[0] = valueOf("preyBox")
  y.predVector = new Array()
    y.predVector[0] = valueOf("predBox");
  for(var i = 0; i < x.vector.length - 1; i++){
        //y.preyVector[i+1] = parseFloat(y.preyVector[i]) * (1+(valueOf("rRange")*(1-(parseFloat(y.preyVector[i])/valueOf("KRange"))))) - (valueOf("sRange") * parseFloat(y.preyVector[i]) * parseFloat(y.predVector[i]))
    y.preyVector[i+1] = y.preyVector[i] * (1+valueOf("rRange")*(1-y.preyVector[i]/valueOf("KRange"))) - valueOf("sRange")*y.preyVector[i]*y.predVector[i]
    y.predVector[i+1] = (1-valueOf("uRange"))*y.predVector[i] + valueOf("vRange")*y.predVector[i] * y.preyVector[i]
    }
}
```

Funnily enough this is pretty much exactly what my Python code did as well, but I didn't even bat an eye.